# Android-Spinner Small issue

Tags: android

Spinner Feed Class

```
public class SpinnerFeed {
    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

}
Function to get records from a url

```
public String readFeed() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // domain intentionally obfuscated for security reasons
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("statesURL");
    try 
    {
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
        }
       } else {
        Log.e(MainActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
      }
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

Finally my spinner code which is working,

```
String readFeed = readFeed();
    // you can use this array to find the state ID based on name
    ArrayList<SpinnerFeed> allStates = new ArrayList<SpinnerFeed>();
    // you can use this array to populate your spinner
    ArrayList<String> states_array = new ArrayList<String>();       

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readFeed);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json.optString("states"));
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          SpinnerFeed statespinner = new SpinnerFeed();
          statespinner.setName(jsonObject.optString("stateName"));
          statespinner.setId(jsonObject.optString("stateID"));
          allStates.add(statespinner);
          states_array.add(jsonObject.optString("stateName"));
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, states_array));

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int pos = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

I just can figure out how to get the ID of selected Item

```
  parent.getItemAtPosition(position); //gives me name  

  parent.getSelectedItemPosition(); //gives me position
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the on itemselected method
write the following:

```
SpinnerFeed statespinner = allstates.get(position);
String id = statespinner.getId(); // to get the id
```